# Fedora command not working

Tags: fedora

This command always worked for me in fedora 26:

`dnf install -y firefox x2go*`

But it now gives an error:

```
Command 'dnf' not found, did you mean:

command 'df' from deb coreutils (8.30-3ubuntu2)

Try: apt install <deb name>
```

Question: How do I make this command work in Fedora 32?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: It maybe you're not running Fedora; the package name would make NO sense in Fedora, and Fedora doesn't use *deb* as it's packages. You need to work out what OS you're actually using, I suspect it's not Fedora.

Comment: This question is unclear and possibly it's also off topic because of the last paragraph that says *How do I make this command work in Fedora 32?* Questions about Fedora are off topic at Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Your package manager is `apt` ; you need to use it to install firefox and x2go.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox x2go*
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't `apt search package` , was looking about x2go and french wiki tells it wasn't in the repo.